# LGT328P does not work as simple V-USB keyboard project. V-USB Keyboard code compiled for LGT328P with no errors but not working (but works on Uno )

Tags: resistor

I got the V-USB library to compile for LGT328P without any errors.

I made a V-USB keyboard for arduino Uno which worked-it involved making a simple circuit using a few zener diodes and
resistors and the V-USB software and schematic I used is documented here:

http://code.rancidbacon.com/ProjectLogArduinoUSB

The code I used for the keyboard is the one given in the example above and copied and pasted below (the other part of the circuit is merely a button to pin 12 -which needs a pull down resistor to ground).
So I migrated the project to the LGT328P.
I got the V-USB library and example sketch to compile for LGT328P without any errors and uploaded the compiled
code to the LGT328P.
So I plugged in my V-USB keyboard built around the LGT328P into a windows 10 PC but it just says USB device
is not recognised-but the code and V-USB circuit must be correct as they worked on the arduino Uno-all I simply did
was recompile it for the LGT328P and wired up the simple V-USB circuit (which uses a few zener diodes and resistors) to the LGT328P.

So how to fix this problem?

I am using Arduino IDE 1.8.5 and I know the LGT328p works already because I got a LED blinking sketch to work on it.

I thought it would just me straightforward to move from the V-USB keyboard I made on the Arduino Uno to the LGT328p
clone but I got the above problem.

I think the problem may be because the LGT328P is a clone board it means it doesn't 100% always compatiable with
arduino libraries such as the V-USB. Be interested to know if anyone else had a similar experience with V-USB and LGT328P.

[image: v-usb circuit used]

v-usb keyboard example code bundled with library:

```
#include "UsbKeyboard.h"

#define BUTTON_PIN 12

// If the timer isr is corrected
// to not take so long change this to 0.
#define BYPASS_TIMER_ISR 1

void setup() {
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(BUTTON_PIN, HIGH);
  
#if BYPASS_TIMER_ISR
  // disable timer 0 overflow interrupt (used for millis)
  TIMSK0&=!(1<<TOIE0); // ++
#endif
}

#if BYPASS_TIMER_ISR
void delayMs(unsigned int ms) {
   /*
  */ 
  for (int i = 0; i < ms; i++) {
    delayMicroseconds(1000);
  }
}
#endif

void loop() {
  
  UsbKeyboard.update();

  digitalWrite(13, !digitalRead(13));

  if (digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN) == 0) {
    
    //UsbKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_B, MOD_GUI_LEFT);
    
    UsbKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_H);
    UsbKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_E);
    UsbKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_L);
    UsbKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_L);
    UsbKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_O);

    UsbKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_SPACE);

    UsbKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_W);
    UsbKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_O);
    UsbKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_R);
    UsbKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_L);
    UsbKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_D);
    //UsbKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_B, MOD_GUI_LEFT);

    UsbKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_ENTER);
#if BYPASS_TIMER_ISR  // check if timer isr fixed.
    delayMs(20);
#else
    delay(20);
#endif
    
   }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [V-USB Keyboard on LGT328P arduino clone not working (but is working on Arduino Uno)](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/95834/v-usb-keyboard-on-lgt328p-arduino-clone-not-working-but-is-working-on-arduino-u)

Comment: @jsotola no, that is a different question-in that question I did not get the code to compile for the LGT328p -in this question I got the code to compile but encountered a new problem. If you had read this new question you would have noticed it is a different question  to the one you give a link to.

Comment: you still have not provided the code ... people will not waste time trying to figure out how you connected everything and what code you are using

Comment: @jsotola okay, no need to be rude. I added the code.

Comment: thank you ... where is the V-USB code?

Comment: Mhh, didn't find any information if someone has tried using V-usb on an LGT328P before (considering they are relatively new to the party). That it doesn't work could still be a problem with the frequency. Or some other difference. LGT328Ps are not complete drop-ins.

Comment: Please check the formatting and presentation of your question in general, and when making edits. A well presented question is more likely to get an answer.

Comment: _"they worked on the arduino Uno-all I simply did was recompile it for the LGT328P "_, you are assuming LGT328P is 100% copycat of ATmega328p, but that's not what they claims, they add a few peripherals and also taken out something like EEPROM, and overclock it so that they can claim they are not a fake ATmege328p, you should ask them what the differences and why it not working.  Unless some Chinese companies, no one write library to ensure the compatibility with such chip...